# Resgatar nome e mostrar em option através do id

Tags: php, html, mysql

Eu tenho um `id` da tabela, exemplo:

usuário com `id = 1`, como eu posso pegar o nome desse usuário utilizando o `id` dele e mostrar em um `input`?

Eu fiz assim:

```
while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array ($sql)) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $dados["id"] ?>" ><?php echo $dados["nome"]; ?></option>
```

Quando ele seleciona a opção mostrar em um `input` a descrição do que seria, por exemplo:

- `id = 1`:  banana (mostrar banana no input)
- `id = 2`: carne (mostrar carne no input)

Sei que é um exemplo esdrúxulo por que não sei como explicar

Comment: Para exibir dados, você poderá utilizar a seguinte forma:        `while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 echo "<input type='text' value='" . $dados['id']. " - ". $dados['nome'] + "' />";`

}

Comment: Desculpa esqueci de um detalhe o input que quero puxar o nome está fora do while

Comment: Você pode criar uma variável fora do loop e setar o valor dela para exibição. Ex: `$valor = ''; while(.....) { $valor = $dados['nome']; ... } echo $valor;

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$id = 1;
$sql = "SELECT nome FROM table WHERE id= '.$id.'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die (mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); ?>


<select name="nome">
  <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
     <option value="<?=$row['id']?>"><?=$row['nome'] ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça uma pesquisa no Banco selecionando todos os campos com o id ou só os campos que você precisa;

```
"SELECT * FROM sua_tabela WHERE id = 'id'"
```

E no input você coloca os dados que desejar.

Answer (score 0):

Como o @LeoLetto disse: Faça uma pesquisa no Banco selecionando todos os campos com o id ou só os campos que você precisa:

`SELECT * FROM sua_tabela WHERE id = 'id'`

E no input você coloca os dados que desejar.

Exemplo com o seu código:

```
$id = '1';
$sql = SELECT * FROM nome_da_sua_tabela WHERE id = 'id'; // usando * você poderá usar todos os campos (nome, id, etc), ou você pode usar SELECT nome, assim você vai selecionar somente o campo nome da tabela que tem o id = 1
$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql); // $con é a variavel que faz a conexão com o banco. 
while($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{ // Lembre de fechar com ?> e no final do seu while você irá abrir o php e fechar o while.


<option value="<?php echo $dados["id"] ?>" ><?php echo $dados["nome"]; ?></option>
```

Comment: `while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array ($sql)) {
                    echo "<option value=". $dados['id'] ."> ". $dados['nome'] . "</option>";
                }`
Para mostrar o select funcionou perfeitamente mas quero mostrar em um input outro campo exemplo:

<input type="text" name="desc" value="<?php $dados['desc'] ?>" readonly/>

mas com isso preciso fazer uma consulta usando o dados['id'] só que ai que me perco

Comment: @Vagner Você pode imprimir o html diretamente no PHP, ou usar da forma que mencionei.

Answer (score 0):

Suponhando que seu `<select>` e consulta `sql` estejam no mesmo arquivo e que você esteja usando o plugin [mysql](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysql.php) do php5 como citado na pergunta:

```
<?php
/*Conexão com base de dados e variável de id sendo preenchida aqui
.
.
*/
$sql = "SELECT id, nome FROM tb_pessoa WHERE id= '$id'";
$select = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die (mysql_error());
$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($select); ?>


<select name="nome">
  <?php 
    foreach($array as $row){
      echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['nome']."</option>"
  ?>
</select>
```